# Software that can automatically shut down/hibernate my computer

Tags: windows, time-management, timer

I have a really poor self discipline, mainly caused by my computer. I'm therefore looking for a software that can automatically shut down (or hibernate) my computer, for Windows 10.

I have some demands for this software I'm looking for:

- That I get a pop up box an hour before the chosen shut down time, where I can choose if I want to turn off the computer, or if I want to put it in hibernate mode.
- That I get a new warning 15-10 minutes before the chosen time, giving me time to quit whatever I'm currently doing.

Does a program like this exists?

Comment: @Thomas I have Windows 10, 64bit version. I'm not an computer expert, so I don't know if I have .NET installed. But I guess it's simple to install it?

As long as I'm currently using the computer, I struggle with actually turning it off. Before going to bed I have to check this and that, and then check the same thing I already checked once more.
I have never turned on the computer after I have turned it off, just to check something.

Comment: Ok, I see. Don't worry about .NET. It can be installed and it's free. I'm gonna implement something like that, since I need it for my son anyway. It may take 2 days to make it complete with an installer etc.

Comment: Under what conditions are you looking to shut down or hibernate?

Comment: @rrirower: as far as I understood it's wall clock time

Comment: @Thomas Wow, that would be really nice of you! Looking forward to it! :)

Comment: @rrirower English is not my native tongue, but if I understand correctly, it's what Thomas Weller answered. 

I want the computer to shut down or hibernate at e.g. 00:00 (12PM I believe). Maybe 01:00 (1PM) in the weekends.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've implemented [Shutdown with warning](http://development.wellisolutions.de/shutdown-with-warning/), because sometimes I have the same issue and I need to prevent my son from gaming until midnight.

The software

- shuts down the PC (via `shutdown -s -t 0` and behaves exactly like that, i.e. it may install updates and there may be programs preventing the PC from shutting down)
- runs on Windows 7 x64 SP1 and Windows 10, should also work on other versions
- has a configurable wall clock time for the shutdown
- has two configurable warning times (default: 60 minutes and 15 minutes)
- is gratis (MIT license)

Downsides / known issues:

- The software is in an early stage and has not been tested intensively.
- It does not offer any protection against termination or similar.
- It cannot be run with command line arguments yet.
- The timers may not work well if the PC falls into hibernation.

Screenshots:

[image: Settings dialog]

[image: Warning]

Comment: If it does not fit your needs yet, leave a comment or report a "bug".

Comment: Sorry my late answer Thomas. Thank you very, very much for this! I'm going on vacation tomorrow, so I'm unable to try it out now. I will give you a feedback when I'm back. 

Thank you!

Comment: @Prentasid: that's fine, thanks. Have nice holidays.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Windows [**`Task scheduler`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) utility

> The Task Scheduler enables you to automatically perform routine tasks
>   on a chosen computer. The Task Scheduler does this by monitoring
>   whatever criteria you choose to initiate the tasks (referred to as
>   triggers) and then executing the tasks when the criteria is met.

Refer [Make Your PC Shut Down at Night (But Only When You’re Not Using It)](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30758/make-your-pc-shut-down-at-night-but-only-when-youre-not-using-it/) to configure your task

---

### [Airytec](http://www.airytec.com/en/switch-off/get.aspx)

> The airytec switch off software will allow you to schedule your
>   shutdown time and it will automatically shutdown PC at the specified
>   time.

- Click on the shutdown icon. In the select schedule drop-down list, choose daily.
- Enter the time when you want to shutdown your PC automatically.
- In the action drop-down list, choose shutdown (It is enabled by default).

[image]

- Click on the enable task button.

[image]

Comment: How do both solutions support "get a pop up box an hour before the chosen shut down time" and "get a new warning 15-10 minutes before the chosen time" ?